# What are all these executable file in the Strawberry Perl folders?

Tags: perl, strawberry-perl

I have downloaded Strawberry-Perl-5.12.1.0 for Windows and was using it for many days. Today I have realized that there is some folder which has many executable files in it.

The folder structure is:

```
c
cpan
cpanplus
perl
ppm
win32
```

What do all these folders signify and what is the use of the executables in these folders?

What I am interested in are the executables I found in folder `c`. I have 38: addr2line.exe ar.exe as.exe c++.exe c++filt.exe cpp.exe dlltool.exe dllwrap.exe dmake.exe elfedit.exe g++.exe gcc.exe gcov.exe gmake.exe gprof.exe i686-w64-mingw32-c++.exe i686-w64-mingw32-g++.exe i686-w64-mingw32-gcc-4.4.3.exe i686-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe iconv.exe ld.exe nm.exe objcopy.exe objdump.exe openssl.exe patch.exe pexports.exe pg_config.exe ranlib.exe readelf.exe size.exe strings.exe strip.exe windmc.exe windres.exe xmlcatalog.exe

In my downloaded folder there is no documentation available and I was not able to find any right information with Google. Maybe I have not queried the right way.

The `--help` options of the executables are only saying what available options are but not the purpose.

Comment: Wait, Googling for "CPAN" failed to find anything? Assumably cpan (and cpanplus) are CPAN shells, used to install packages from CPAN. I'd post an answer, but I don't have a Strawberry install to check on.

Comment: @derobert: Thanks for replying. I have an idea about cpan. What I am interested in is the EXE's I found in folder "c": I have 38 EXE. Which are "addr2line.exe
ar.exe
as.exe
c++.exe
c++filt.exe
cpp.exe
dlltool.exe
dllwrap.exe
dmake.exe
elfedit.exe
g++.exe
gcc.exe
gcov.exe
gmake.exe
gprof.exe
i686-w64-mingw32-c++.exe
i686-w64-mingw32-g++.exe
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc-4.4.3.exe
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe
iconv.exe
ld.exe
nm.exe
objcopy.exe
objdump.exe
openssl.exe
patch.exe
pexports.exe
pg_config.exe
ranlib.exe
readelf.exe
size.exe
strings.exe
strip.exe
windmc.exe
windres.exe
xmlcatalog.exe

 "

Comment: @user430294: That is (from the names) clearly a C compiler (gcc) and associated build chain, plus a few utilities (openssl, etc.). Probably for building xs modules.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strawberry C comes with a C compiler and build tools to enable you to compile new XS distributions from CPAN.  The tools will be automatically properly run when needed if you install module distributions; you don't need to worry about them.